# Ubuntu 17.10 stops responding to mouse or keyboard

Tags: 17.10

My Ubuntu 17.10 keeps becoming unresponsive. At the time I usually have no more than 2 windows open - in this case a terminal window and one Firefox tab. The mouse cursor responds to mouse movements, but not clicks, and the cursor has changed to a hand (rather than the usual arrow). I can't get the keyboard to do anything. So I've needed to press the reset button. This has happened regularly for the last few days (I installed Ubuntu last weekend). 
What's the best way to diagnose this problem? (I'm a Linux novice)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in the past weeks. Usually because of an un-finished drag job..

> A quick restart should resolve your problem